# Convert a multidimensional array to JSON with node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm getting a BIG multidimensional array after combining few simple arrays, now I need to convert it in a JSON string right before sending it to Mongodb. Here is the array structure:

```
[ '0',
  [ [ 'id', 1 ],
    [ 'country', 0 ],
    [ 'people', 3 ],
    [ 'name', 'WELLINGTON ALFRED' ],
    [ 'location', 'hill' ],
    [ 'filename', 243245.PDF]]]
```

What's the best practice to do it in Node.js?
Thank's in advance!

Comment: What is creating the array like this in the first place?

Comment: @Explosion Pills I'm iterating the BIG array and sending each sub array to Mongodb, this is only a sub-array with '0' as index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you totally can use `JSON.stringify`

`string_for_mongo = JSON.stringify(your_array)`

but you also can use any of [these](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/) drivers for mongodb

if you want to convert these arrays to object you can just use something like this

```
pairs = {}
for ( pair in your_array[1] ) { pairs[your_array[1][pair][0]] = your_array[1][pair][1] }
objekt = {}
objekt[your_array[0]] = pairs
```

I think there is no better solution than not to use such an arrays. Try to form data in objects from the beginning.

Comment: this is the result of `console.log(string_for_mongo); ["0",[["id",1],["country",0],["people",3],["name","WELLINGTON ALFRED"],["location","hill"],["filename","243245.PDF"]]]`

Comment: ...and yes this is a valid JSON for JSONLint (JSON validator).

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method for the same.

You can use the following function:

```
//array
var arr = [
    ["Status", "Name", "Marks", "Position"], 
    ["active", "Akash", 10.0, "Web Developer"],
    ["active", "Vikash", 10.0, "Front-end-dev"],
    ["deactive", "Manish", 10.0, "designer"],
    ["active", "Kapil", 10.0, "JavaScript developer"],
    ["active", "Manoj", 10.0, "Angular developer"],
];

//javascript create JSON object from two dimensional Array
function arrayToJSONObject (arr){
    //header
    var keys = arr[0];

    //vacate keys from main array
    var newArr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);

    var formatted = [],
    data = newArr,
    cols = keys,
    l = cols.length;
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var d = data[i],
                    o = {};
            for (var j=0; j<l; j++)
                    o[cols[j]] = d[j];
            formatted.push(o);
    }
    return formatted;
}
```

Reference: [Click Here](https://www.tutsmake.com/convert-array-to-json-object-javascript/)

> Note: This might not give the output required for the input given in the question. I've provided the type of input this will work in `arr`.